# The most clear and concise way to describe SSH commands in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

Usually I make the following job in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` to execute commands on a remote server via SSH:

```
# The job
deploy:
  script:
    # I've omitted the SSH setup here
    - |
      ssh gitlab@example.com "
        # Makes the server print the executed commands to stdout. Otherwise only the command output is printed. Required for monitoring and debug.
        set -x &&

        # Executes some commands
        cd /var/www/example &&
        command1 &&
        command2 &&
        command3 &&
        command4 &&
        command5
      "
```

It works correctly, but the YAML code looks too complicated:

- The `set -x` command is more a boilerplate than a useful code. It's not required for ordinary CI commands because GitLab CI prints them automatically.
- `&&` on every line is boilerplate too. They make the execution stop when one of a commands fails. Otherwise the next commands will be executed when one fails (in contrast to ordinary job commands).
- All the SSH commands are a single YAML string therefore editors don't highlight the comments and commands so the code is hard to read.

Is there a more clear and convenient way to execute multiple commands on a remote machine through SSH without the cons described above?

I'd like to not use external deployment tools like Ansible to keep the CD configuration as simple as possible (default POSIX/Linux commands are welcome). I'v also considered running each command in a separate `ssh` call but I'm afraid it may increase the job execution time because of multiple SSH connection establishments (but I'm not sure):

```
deploy:
  script:
    - ssh gitlab@example.com "cd /var/www/example"
    - ssh gitlab@example.com "command1"
    - ssh gitlab@example.com "command2"
    # ...
```

Answer (score 5):

A more concise and clear way is to use `set -e`. It makes the whole script fail when one of the commands fails. It lets you not use `&&` on every line:

```
# The job
deploy:
  script:
    # I've omitted the SSH setup here
    - |
      ssh gitlab@example.com "
        # Makes the server print the executed commands to stdout. Makes the execution stop when one of the commands fails.
        set -x -e

        # Executes some commands
        cd /var/www/example
        command1
        command2
        command3
        command4
        command5

        # Even complex commands
        if [ -f ./.env ]
          then command6
          else
            echo 'Environment is not set up'
            exit 1
        fi
      "
```

Answer (score 3):

Keep your commands in a separate file *remote.sh* without `set -x` and `&&`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Executes some commands
cd /var/www/example
command1
command2
command3
command4
command5
```

And use `eval` to run them on remote server:

```
deploy:
  script:
    - ssh gitlab@example.com "eval '$(cat ./remote.sh)'"
```

This approach will keep YAML simple and clean and meet all your requirements.

Comment: Plus you can use shell script locally if needed

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it enables the sh syntax highlight. But unfortunately it has lacks. The executed commands are not printed (`set -x` is still required) and the execution doesn't stop when a command from `remote.sh` fails (`&&` is still required). Also I can't use `'` in `remote.sh` because it interferes with the CI command text.

Comment: The `'` problem can be solved by running `ssh gitlab@example.com "bash -" < ./remote.sh` or `cat ./remote.sh | ssh gitlab@example.com "bash -"`